# Blender app.timer does not function concurrently with python-osc server thread

Tags: python

I want to run a python-osc server concurrently with an app.timer in a python script. The problem is that I can get the server and timer to run separately but not together. The dispatcher mappings are contained in an external config file and this seems to work fine. There appears to be something about a running server that upsets the timer. I wonder whether any kind soul can assist? Any suggestions would be most welcome. Thx in advance...  This is the test set-up:

```
def  DataPathsImport():  
    print("Reading in config data...") 
    with open("/Users/<path_to_config_file>/linker_config.yaml", 'r') as y:
        dlinks = (yaml.load(y, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)) 

def print_hello():
    print("hello")
    return 1.0

class OSC_Server(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Set up server"""
    bl_idname = "wm.osc_server_operator"
    bl_label = "OSCMainThread"

    count= 0 

    def execute(self, context):
        global _report

        try:
            self.dispatcher = dispatcher.Dispatcher()
            links = DataPathsImport()
            for link in links:
                dataTuple = (link.get('tag'), link.get('dpath'), link.get('dtype'), \
                    link.get('action'))
                self.dispatcher.map(link.get('addr'), osc_callback_router, dataTuple)
        except: # be specific with error type
            print(f"There has been an error when assigning address: {link.get('addr')}")
        try: 
            print(f"Creating server on port: {port}, at ip address: {ip}")
            self.server = BlockingOSCUDPServer((ip, port), self.dispatcher) 
            self.server_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.server.serve_forever())
            self.server_thread.start()
            bpy.app.timers.register(print_hello)

        except OSError as err:
            _report[1] = err
            return {'CANCELLED'}

    def cancel(self, context):
        print("OSC server.shutdown()")
        self.server.shutdown()
        return {'CANCELLED'}


classes = {
    OSC_Server
}


def register():
    from bpy.utils import register_class
    for cls in classes:
        register_class(cls)


def unregister():
    from bpy.utils import unregister_class
    for cls in reversed(classes): # unregister classes in the reverse order that they were registered
        unregister_class(cls)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    bpy.ops.wm.osc_server_operator()
```

Comment: Have you checked if the ["Gotchas"](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_gotcha.html#strange-errors-using-threading-module) apply?

Comment: For others vaguely interested in this topic: remove the brackets from serve_forever() i.e. change to serve_forever. If you don't, the running server will block anything else from running concurrently :)